# .kv file not working properly in visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, kivy, kivymd

I'm trying to create a python app in Visual Studio Code and everything is good except Kivy.
The app is running but I get one of these errors in the .kv  file: "final newline missing" or after I update the settings: "trailing newline" and "trailing whitespace". I mean app is still working and displaying widgets but still how can I fix the code? Please help out.
Here's my very very simple code:

```
#:kivy 2.0.0

<FloatLayout>:
    Button:
        text: "tf"
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.